# Filling out form using ember-rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm following a tutorial that is about a year old so there is some syntax that has been depreciated. 
I type some text in an input field and hit enter. I should see an alert box pop up with the text I've just written. Instead, when I load the page and look at the console, I immediately get this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

It says I have an error in my controller but there doesn't seem to be any syntax problems in my code.

When I type and hit enter, there is no alert box and an error on the console says:

Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'addEntry'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

My application template looks like this:

```
<div id = "container">
  <h1>Emberails</h1>

  {{ input value=newEntryName enter="addEntry" }}

  {{ newEntryName }}

</div>
```

My ApplicationController looks like this:

```
Emberapp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend(
    addEntry: function(){
      alert(this.get('newEntryName'));
      this.set('newEntryName', "");
    }
)
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing curly braces in your call to `extend`.

```
Emberapp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    addEntry: function() {
      alert(this.get('newEntryName'));
      this.set('newEntryName', "");
    },
});
```

Comment: Yup, just figured it out and then came on here to post the answer. Thanks.